# Group structure on the dual group of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, duality-theorems

Let $G$ be a finite group (not necessarily abelian), and consider the dual group $\hat{G}$, whose underlying set is the irreducible representations of $G$. My question is: What is the group structure on $\hat{G}$?

(I originally thought that by extending the underlying set to ``all representations'', I have a natural semi-ring structure on this set, namely the semi-ring of characters. However, this is not the notion of duality we want because the dual of the dual does not give us back anything that resembles the group)

(Another thought is that perhaps one can somehow exploit the group structure on $\mathbb{C}[G]$?)

Thank you for your help,

Maithreya

$\textbf{EDIT due to comments}$: I found where i read about this!: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247b.1.07w/notes10.pdf (I had lost it before) - See the end of page 5, and you see that the underlying set is indeed the collection of irreducible representations and he calls it the dual group - he says he will "get back to the group structure'' but I do not think he does.

Comment: Every character on $G$ is trivial on $G'$ and $G/G'$ is abelian. so $\hat G$ should be isomorphic to $G/G'$ (right?)

Comment: @yanko i think we are talking about different notions - you are thinking about the definition in the abelian group case (i think), i think i have figured it out though.. so give me a moment to confirm if i have, and if so, I will delete this question.

Comment: Elements of the dual group correspond to $1$-dimensional representations: the product in the dual group is just the tensor product.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, once again, i think you have the definition for abelian groups in mind.. not the general notion. In particular, for a nonabelian group, elements of the dual need be 1 dimensional.

Comment: What I wrote is true for abelian groups and for nonabelian groups.

Comment: The set of irreducible representation of a nonabelian group does not have any group structure, it is just a set. It is certainly not called "the dual group"! (As for your parenthetical paragraph: the set of all representations is not a ring, only a semiring: there are no additive inverses)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Aha! found where i read about this!: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247b.1.07w/notes10.pdf - see the end of page 5.. and you see that he calls it the dual group - he says he will ``get back to the group structure'' but I do not think he does. (Regarding the fact that it is a semi-ring, fair enough)

Comment: @yanko - my attempt at the group structure did not work out as planned, so the question is still unsolved for me.

Comment: I don't know what Tao was planning to return to later, but the set of irreps of a nonabelian group does not have any sensible group structure — it is a fact of nature.